# manjaro lxqt kwin desktop switch hotkeys

Tags: manjaro, kwin, lxqt

Linux mvalitov-pc 4.20.17-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 19 18:07:36 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I installed `lxqt` and `kwin`, and I can't find how to configure switching between desktops. In `xfce`, I used the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd>. In the shortcut settings there are only commands for switching to a specific desktop, and not for swith to next/prev.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same issue with `lxqt` on Lubuntu. There the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> hotkeys works correctly but in Ubuntu I used to change it to another hotkeys pair. So I have spent time seeking way to set them. I ended up with using `xbindkeys-config` app and a script from [here](https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2011/03/04/switching-workspace-in-gnome-via-the-command-line/).

To install `xbindkeys-config`:

```bsh
sudo apt install xbindkeys-config
```

For running script you may need `wmctrl` installed:

```bsh
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

The script failed executing `NUM_WORKSPACES` and `NUM_COLS` variables, so I just set them explicitly:

```
NUM_WORKSPACES=4
NUM_COLS=4
```

Here is my final script version:

```
#!/bin/bash

CMD="$1"

NUM_WORKSPACES=4
NUM_COLS=4

#NUM_WORKSPACES=`gconftool-2 --get /apps/metacity/general/num_workspaces`
#NUM_COLS=`gconftool-2 --get /apps/panel/applets/workspace_switcher_screen0/prefs/num_rows`

NUM_ROWS=`echo "$NUM_WORKSPACES / $NUM_COLS" | bc`

CURRENT_WS=`wmctrl -d | grep \* | cut -d " " -f 1`

MOVE_LEFT="- $NUM_ROWS"
MOVE_RIGHT="+ $NUM_ROWS"
MOVE_UP="-1"
MOVE_DOWN="+1"

case $CMD in

"Left" )
    NEW_WS=`echo $CURRENT_WS "-" $NUM_ROWS | bc`
    if [[ $NEW_WS -lt 0 ]]; then NEW_WS=$CURRENT_WS; fi
    ;;

"Right" )
    NEW_WS=`echo $CURRENT_WS "+" $NUM_ROWS | bc`
    if [[ $NEW_WS -ge $NUM_WORKSPACES ]]; then NEW_WS=$CURRENT_WS; fi
    ;;

"Up" )
    WS_COL=`echo $CURRENT_WS "%" $NUM_ROWS | bc`
    if [[ $WS_COL -eq 0 ]]; then
    {
        NEW_WS=$CURRENT_WS
    }
    else
    {
        NEW_WS=`echo $CURRENT_WS "- 1" | bc`
    }; fi
    ;;

"Down" )
    NEW_WS=`echo $CURRENT_WS "+ 1" | bc`
    NEW_WS_COL=`echo $NEW_WS "%" $NUM_ROWS | bc`
    if [[ $NEW_WS_COL -eq 0 ]]; then NEW_WS=$CURRENT_WS; fi
    ;;

* )
    NEW_WS=$CMD

esac

wmctrl -s $NEW_WS
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, @AdminBee. Yes, I checked double square brackets in terminal and it works well. And then when I run scripts by `sh`, if shows the `29: [[: not found` error.

Comment: @AdminBee I found that when I run the script with `bash` command it doesn't show the error. It seems to me that `sh` is not equal to `bash` in my system. Such a surprise for me...

Comment: Yeah, thank you for clarification @AdminBee. I have edited my answer.